# What is the difference between foldr and apply in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

Programming language: Scheme/DrRacket

I see no difference in usage between `foldr` and `apply`

Can anyone explain how they are different? As far as I can tell you can the same thing with foldr that you can with apply. Thank you!

Comment: They're only equivalent if the function is associative.

Comment: `foldr` is like the `reduce` function in Python, `Array.prototype.reduce` in JavaScript, and `array_reduce` in PHP.

Comment: @Barmar A lot of beginners ask how `reduce` is different from `apply` too. I don't think that comparison is necessarily so useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're very different, although in some cases they may be equivalent.

---

```
(apply func '(1 2 3))
```

is equivalent to

```
(func 1 2 3)
```

---

```
(foldr func 0 '(1 2 3))
```

is equivalent to

```
(func (func (func 3 0) 2) 1)
```

---

In cases where the function is associative and commutative, and it allows you to provide a variable number of arguments, the results will be the same. For example

```
(apply + '(1 2 3)) == (foldr + 0 '(1 2 3))
```

But `foldr` can be used to combine the results of functions that just take two arguments, or use more flexible ways to combine the results.

For more information about `foldr`, see [Map, Filter, Foldr in DrRacket/Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872852/map-filter-foldr-in-drracket-scheme)